# How to change the date from YYYY-MM-DD to YYDD-MM-YY in python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy

I have a MySQL database, and there is a column in which I have stored the date. Now the requirement is I need to replace the dd with YY. and I want to do this using python(Pandas)

for eg date that i have is 2032-11-16, and I want 2016-11-32.

uptill now my approach is shown below

```
df = pd.read_csv('p1006_freight_rates.csv')
df['year'] = zip(*df['date'].apply(lambda x: (x[:4], x[5:])))
```

the above approach is absolutely wrong, I have also tried the string replace but that too had some issue.

and also please tell me how to save the update in mysql.

Comment: In what column is this date string located?

Comment: '2016-11-32' is the invalid date

Comment: YYDD-MM-YY? Really?

Comment: _**@Ponnarasu**_: It is the desired output format `YYDD-MM-YY`  or `century partDD-MM-year part`

Comment: @COLDSPEED  Column name is date

Comment: @NikhilGupta Does `df['date'] = d.str[-2:] + d.str[2:-2] + d.str[:2]` work?

Comment: Actually when the data was uploaded in the mysql file then at that data was uploaded in a wrong way, it was expected to be YYYY-MM-DD but it was uploaded YYDD-MM-YY and because of which all the data is wrong. and I dont want to reupload the data as it takes so much time so I am looking for the alternative

Answer (score 0):

[`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module could help you with that:

`datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format1).strftime(format2)`

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-1-25", '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

prints `"01/25/13"`.

If you can't live with the leading zero, try this:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-1-25", '%Y-%m-%d')
print '{0}/{1}/{2:02}'.format(dt.month, dt.day, dt.year % 100)
```

This prints `"1/25/13"`.

EDIT: This may not work on every platform:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-1-25", '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%-m/%d/%y')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and straight forward method would be like this:

```
xx = [
    '2032-11-16',
    '2011-22-33'
]
df = pd.DataFrame(xx,columns=['date'])
df['new_date'] = df.date.map(lambda x:x[:2]+x[-2:]+x[4:8]+x[2:4])
df
```

Comment: I am trying this but it is showing the 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You can use: `df.date.dtypes` to check the exact type of your input. As it's date, it should not be float.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a date string that you KNOW is in the format YYDD-MM-YY, then just use this:

```
new_str = old_str;
new_str[2:4] = old_str[8:10]
new_str[8:10] = old_str[2:4]
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working, I am getting the same entries

Comment: If that does not work there's something seriously wrong.